# Network card power management settings

Tags: registry

Can anyone confirm that the following registry contains network card configurations?

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002bE10318}\DeviceNumber
```

I need to disable the options of letting the computer turn off the nic to save power.

I set

```
SavePowerNowEnabled = 0
```

Checked power management options of the card and it was still enabled, rebooted and checked but still shows enabled even though it's set to 0.

Also I found a post that setting PnPCapabilities to 24 stops the pc from turning off the nic.

When changing the checkboxes in the front end the value does change to 24. When I enable and set the value back to 0 and manually change it back to 24. The check boxes are still enabled even after a reboot.
I really need it to show as disabled in the front end not just a trick that shows it enabled but doesn't actually put the nic to sleep.

Comment: For windows 7 the following may be of some help.
https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2740020#LetMeFixItMyselfAlways

Comment: updated post. The PnP value does change to 24 when setting the front end to disable power options but after I re-enable them so it's set back to 0 or 256, when I change it back to 24, even after a reboot the front end is still checked.

Comment: Scratch that it did work, was trying in the wrong value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002bE10318}\DeviceNumber\PnPCapabilities
```

to 0x18 did the trick on reboot.

Answer (score 0):

The value is 24 decimal, but I believe Windows 10 x64 defaults to hex. So if the check box hex under base is checked, then input 18. Or check the decimal box and put in 24.

You can also go into device manager and select the adapter under network adapters, right click, properties, power management, and uncheck allow the computer to turn off this device to save power.

What happened to me (Dell Inspiron Ryzen 7 2700u + Vega 10) is even though I had all power settings at maximum performance with CPU parking off, once in a while I would turn on the PC and it would say no network device is connected (and would not show in device manager). Rebooting and shutdown did not solve the issue. I had to shutdown, plug the PC into the power cable, and turn it on to get it to show again. This registry method should work without having to do all that.